# Laravel form validation doesn't seem to work like CodeIgniter

Tags: php, laravel

I recently change framework from Codeigniter to laravel and had some difficulties in form validation

How do you validate in laravel as simple as `$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');` in CodeIgniter

Comment: What? X framework doesn't work like Y framework? Preposterous!. Srsly now, have a look at the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation).

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Laravel and Codeigniter

if you want to know how validation rules can be add in laravel then please check [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Here is an example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'firstname' => 'required',
    ]);

    // its declare the firstname field validation rules
    // all validation errors will be found in $validatedData variable 
}
```